# If you continuously delta hedge a long option position will you be flat at expiry regardless of realized vol?

Tags: options, hedging, delta, gamma

Learning about gamma and am confused about practical gamma trading strategies and struggling to understand how they can be monetized. Is all gamma just about setting limit orders above and below and hoping they hit? or if you could in theory hedge continuously could you still make money? Even if the option is held to expiry.

I understand that you can continuously delta hedge a long gamma position and gain on mark-to-market of the option - but in cases where you hold to expiry it doesn't make sense to me. It seems to me that continuously hedging delta (in theory) leaves you without a position constantly - and therefore no gains from delta position regardless of how volatile the underlying is. Therefore at expiry would realized PnL not be zero (even if you paid 0 premium to get in?)

Assuming 0 hedge cost/slippage here. Also, let's ignore theta and assume the premium paid to get into the option was 0.

If someone could point me to some literature about this topic I would also appreciate it!

Comment: Absolutely not. Even if the BS model were true and you use the wrong vol for it you won't be flat. See a re-derivation [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68306/58786) of this well-known fact.